# ProgressBar in Fragment not showing in proccess reading

Tags: android, progress-bar, nfc

My `ProgressBar` do not show during execution of the process.

My application reads an NFC message. It is necessary to display `ProgressBar` during the reading process and to display a message in `TextView` about it. When the reading is finished, `ProgressBar` disappears and "Success" is displayed.
But it does not work for me.

```
public class NFCReadFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = NFCReadFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public static NFCReadFragment newInstance() {
        return new NFCReadFragment();
    }

    private TextView mTvMessage;
    private Listener mListener;
    private ProgressBar mProgres;

    OnReadDataPass onReadDataPass;

    public interface OnReadDataPass {
        void onReadDataPass(byte[][] data);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {

        mTvMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        mProgres = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarRead);
        mProgres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mListener = (MainActivity) context;
        mListener.onDialogDisplayed();
        onReadDataPass = (OnReadDataPass) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener.onDialogDismissed();
    }

    public void passReadData(byte[][] data){

        onReadDataPass.onReadDataPass(data);
    }

    public void onNfcDetected(Ndef ndef){

        mProgres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        byte[][] buf = readFromNFC(ndef);
        if(buf != null) {
            passReadData(buf);
        }
    }

    private byte[][] readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) {

        mTvMessage.setText("Идёт процесс считывания");

        try {
            ndef.connect();
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
            if(ndefMessage != null) {
                byte buf[][] = new byte[ndefMessage.getRecords().length][];
                for (int i = 0; i < ndefMessage.getRecords().length; i++) {
                    buf[i] = ndefMessage.getRecords()[i].getPayload();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "readFromNFC: " + "success");
                mTvMessage.setText("Успешно");
                ndef.close();

                return buf;
            }

            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "readFromNFC: " + "NFC tag null");
                mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения");
                return null;
            }

        } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения");
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            mProgres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

xml Fragment

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Чтение тэга NFC"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nfc"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRead"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Приложите телефон к метке NFC"/>
    `enter code here`  </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements Listener, 
    NFCReadFragment.OnReadDataPass {

    private Button mBtRead;
    private NFCReadFragment mNfcReadFragment;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean isDialogDisplayed = false;
    private boolean isWrite = false;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

        initViews();
        initNFC();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
    R.anim.anim_alfa);

        mBtRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mBtRead.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                view.startAnimation(animAlpha);
                showReadFragment();
            }
        });
        //  mBtRead.setOnClickListener(view -> showReadFragment());
    }

    private void initNFC(){
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    private void showReadFragment() {

        mNfcReadFragment = (NFCReadFragment) 
     getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NFCReadFragment.TAG);

        if (mNfcReadFragment == null) {
            mNfcReadFragment = NFCReadFragment.newInstance();
        }
        mNfcReadFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),NFCReadFragment.TAG);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogDisplayed() {

        isDialogDisplayed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogDismissed() {

        isDialogDisplayed = false;
        isWrite = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new 
     IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter ndefDetected = new 
     IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter techDetected = new 
    IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter[] nfcIntentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{techDetected,tagDetected,ndefDetected};

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, 
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
            mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, 
    nfcIntentFilter, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
            mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: "+intent.getAction());

        if(tag != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.message_tag_detected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

            if (isDialogDisplayed) {
                mNfcReadFragment = (NFCReadFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NFCReadFragment.TAG);
                mNfcReadFragment.onNfcDetected(ndef);
            }
        }
    }

    public void transfToData(byte[][] buf){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tabs.class);
        intent.putExtra("record_ndef", buf);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private byte[][] readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) {

        try {
            ndef.connect();
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
            byte buf[][] = new byte[ndefMessage.getRecords().length][];

            //ID[i] = GetId();
            //i++;
            String f;
            for (int i = 0; i < ndefMessage.getRecords().length; i++) {
                buf[i] = ndefMessage.getRecords()[i].getPayload();
                f = new String(buf[i]);
            }

            ndef.close();

            return buf;

        } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    private String GetId(){
        Tag myTag = (Tag) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        String ID = bytesToHexString(myTag.getId());
        return ID;
    }

    private String bytesToHexString(byte[] src){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("0x");
        if(src == null || src.length <= 0){
            return null;
        }

        char[] buffer = new char[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < src.length; i++){
            buffer[0] = Character.forDigit((src[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F, 16);
            buffer[1] = Character.forDigit(src[i] & 0x0F, 16);
            System.out.println(buffer);
            stringBuilder.append(buffer);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadDataPass(byte[][] data) {
        if(data != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tabs.class);
            intent.putExtra("record_ndef", data);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        openQuitDialog();
    }

    private void openQuitDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        quitDialog.setTitle("Закрыть приложение?");

        quitDialog.setPositiveButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.runFinalization();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        quitDialog.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        quitDialog.show();
    }
}
```

It is necessary to display `ProgressBar` during the reading process.
At the moment, it is only displayed before going into the second activity.

Comment: Maybe your `ProgressBar ` is hided by another view in your xml

Comment: Can you post your XML code?

Comment: from where you are calling onNfcDetected(Ndef ndef) method?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Zayid Mohammed, in onNewIntent(Intent intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **onNfcDetected()** method is called only after getting the NFC details not while reading NFC. You can remove **mProgres.setVisibility(View.GONE);** from fragment **initViews()** method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. This example was taken from the site:
https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/10/android-reading-and-writing-nfc-tags.html
Where exactly is reading Tag NFC?

Comment: You just remove/comment mProgres.setVisibility(View.GONE); from NFCReadFragment's initViews() methos. And check whether this is the behaviour you wanted.

Comment: If you delete mProgres.setVisibility (View.GONE), ProgressBar appears when the button is clicked (the occurrence of a fragment). I need to show it from the moment of detection of the tag

Comment: Yes. From where you're calling readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) in your ManinActivity?

Comment: Actually, nowhere, the readout occurs in the fragment and is passed to mainActpivity via onReadData.
The function readNdef in MainActivity remained from previous attempts and is not used, I apologize for this.

Comment: @EgorVasilyev you don't have to apologize brother. reading NFC tag takes fraction of a second i guess. i don't have an NFC tag to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly hiding the progress bar with:

```
finally {
    mProgres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Since it runs on every cycle.
Create some logs in your code to verify it. I would add some Log.d() every time I set the view to GONE so I know what is going on.

Why don't you make all the work inside an AsyncTask and call View.GONE onPostExecute()? It's way cleaner.

Comment: He want to show ProgressBar while reading, and finally {} block is very end statement. So finally block is not the issue. And yeah using AsyncTask is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the progress bar with

> mProgres.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

***Do not use GONE***, Once you use that,you can not use this ProgressBar next.

So ,your ProgressBar will not show in procress reading.

You can try below:

```
private void initViews(View view) {
    mTvMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
    mProgres = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarRead);
    mProgres.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```